# Convert object to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, javascript-objects

In input of function is an object who has this structure:

```
{
  tag: 'a', //type of html object
  content: "blabal", //inner content
  attr: {
    href: "vk.com",
    id: 'someId'
  },
  events: {
    click: 'alert(this.href)',
    focus: 'this.className="active"'
  },
  style: {
    width:"100px"
  }
}
```

It describes an HTML element. It has to return an HTML element with specified properties. How to parse it? I have something like this:

```
elemen={
  tag:'a',
  content:"blabal",
  attr:{
    href:"vk.com",
    id:'someId'
  },
  events:{
   click:'alert(this.href)',
   focus:'this.className="active"'
  },
  style:{
    width:"100px"
  }
};
console.log(elemen.tag);
var node = document.createElement(elemen.tag);
node.innerHTML= elemen.content;

for(var prop in elemen.events){

  var fun =new Function(elemen.events[prop]);
  console.log(fun);
  node.bind(prop, fun);
//   divv.bind(prop, fun);
}
```

Comment: Is templates such as mustache or jquery tmpl an alternative?

Comment: Yes. He has only structure like i described. There is no alternative

Comment: Note that a JavaScript object is not JSON. JSON is a data format, and in JavaScript you can only have JSON in a string. See [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/3853934)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using only javascript

```
 var _createElem = document.createElement(""+_elem.tag+""); 
 _createElem.innerHTML = _elem.content;

//set attributes
for(var keys in _elem.attr){
  _createElem.setAttribute(''+keys+'',_elem.attr[keys])
 }
//set style 
 for(var keys in _elem.style){
  _createElem.setAttribute(''+keys+'',_elem.style[keys])
 }
//set events
for(var keys in _elem.events){
_createElem.setAttribute('on'+keys,_elem.events[keys])
} 
document.getElementById("demoDiv").appendChild(_createElem)
```

Note: The elem has got both `onclick` & `href` , you may need to `return true/false` as per your requirement

Comment: Wrong fiddle. And whats up with all these unneeded quotes?

Comment: [Don't use on*event* HTML attributes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to register events on `Element` and [`.bind(thisArg)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to have specified argument as `this-context`

```js
var elemen = {
  tag: 'a',
  content: "blabal",
  attr: {
    href: "vk.com",
    id: 'someId'
  },
  events: {
    click: 'alert(this.href)',
    focus: 'this.className="active"'
  }
};
var node = document.createElement(elemen.tag);
node.innerHTML = elemen.content;
for (var attr in elemen.attr) {
  node.setAttribute(attr, elemen.attr[attr]);
}
for (var prop in elemen.events) {
  node.addEventListener(prop, new Function(elemen.events[prop]).bind(node));
}
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```js
const objectToHTML = function(obj) {
  const element = document.createElement(obj.tag)
  element.innerHTML = obj.content
  for (const name in obj.attr) {
    const value = obj.attr[name]
    element.setAttribute(name, value)
  }
  for (const name in obj.events) {
    const listener = new Function(obj.events[name]).bind(element)
    element.addEventListener(name, listener)
  }
  for (const property in obj.style) {
    const value = obj.style[property]
    element.style[property] = value
  }
  return element
}
```

To create an event listener from string, you have to convert it to function using the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), bind context to it using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (otherwise the function would be executed with `window` as context), and finally, use [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

The rest is rather obvious.

You can use this function like that:

```js
const element = objectToHTML({
  tag: 'a',
  content: "blabal",
  attr: {
    href: "vk.com",
    id: 'someId'
  },
  events: {
    click: 'alert(this.href)',
    focus: 'this.className="active"'
  },
  style: {
    width: "100px"
  }
})

document.body.appendChild(element)
```

See demo:

```js
const objectToHTML = function(obj) {
  const element = document.createElement(obj.tag)
  element.innerHTML = obj.content
  for (const name in obj.attr) {
    const value = obj.attr[name]
    element.setAttribute(name, value)
  }
  for (const name in obj.events) {
    const listener = new Function(obj.events[name]).bind(element)
    element.addEventListener(name, listener)
  }
  for (const property in obj.style) {
    const value = obj.style[property]
    element.style[property] = value
  }
  return element
}

const element = objectToHTML({
  tag: 'a',
  content: "blabal",
  attr: {
    href: "vk.com",
    id: 'someId'
  },
  events: {
    click: 'alert(this.href)',
    focus: 'this.className="active"'
  },
  style: {
    width: "100px"
  }
})

document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend this form, is more adaptable.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 
  function init_() {

    function action__(type, element, convert, a) {
      if (type == "function") {
        if (convert.create[a] != null) {
          try {
            var new_ = convert.create[a](element[a]);
          } catch (rrr) {
            rrr = (rrr.toString());

            if (rrr.indexOf('2 arguments') != -1 && Object.keys(element[a]).length != 0) {
              for (v in element[a]) {
                convert.create[v] = element[a][v];
                var new_ = convert.create;
              }
            };
          }
          convert['create'] = new_;
        }

      };

      if (type == "object") {
        for (f in element[a]) {
          convert.create[a][f] = element[a][f];
        }
      }

      if (type == "string" && a != "events") {
        convert.create[a] = (element[a]);
      } else if (type == "string" && a == "events") {
        for (ev in element[a]) {
          var type = convert.detectType(convert.create, ev);
          if (type == "function") {
            convert.create.addEventListener(ev, new Function(element[a][ev]));
          }
        };
      };



      return convert.create;
    };


    function createElement(elements) {

      var finished = [];

      if (typeof elements.tagName == "undefined" && !elements.length) {
        elements = [elements];
      }

      for (r = 0; r < elements.length; r++) {
        var element = elements[r];
        if (element) {
          var convert = {
            create: document,
            detectType: function(element, attribute) {
              var type = "string";
              if (typeof element[attribute] != "undefined") {
                type = typeof element[attribute];
              };
              return type;
            },
            add: function(new_) {
              if (new_ && new_ != "undefined") {
                this.create = new_;
              }
            }

          };

          for (a in element) {

            var type = convert.detectType(convert.create, a);
            var returner = action__(type, element, convert, a);
            convert.add(returner);
          }


          finished.push(convert.create);
        };

      }
      return (finished);

    };

    var minifi_function = init_.toString();
    
    var elements = [{
      createElement: 'a', 
      innerHTML: "blabal", 
      setAttribute: {
        href: "vk.com",
        id: 'someId',
        style: "height:200px;"
      },
      events: {
        click: 'alert(this.href)',
        focus: 'this.className="active"'
      },
      style: {
        width: "100px"
      }
    }, {
      createElement: 'div', 
      innerHTML: "see my content", 
      setAttribute: {
        ['data-link']: "vk.com",
        id: 'someId2',
        style: "height:200px;background:red;"
      },
      events: {
        click: 'prompt("Copy",' + minifi_function + ')',
        focus: 'this.className="activediv"'
      },
      style: {
        width: "100px"
      }
    }];



    var elementos = createElement(elements);
    console.log(elementos);
    for (p = 0; p < elementos.length; p++) {
      document.body.appendChild(elementos[p]);
    }

  }

  init_();
}
```